# Self join SQL query to return parents that have at least two same children

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, self-join

I have this table setup.

```
create table holdMyBeer 
(
     Id int, 
     Name varchar(20)
)

insert into holdMyBeer 
values (1, 'park'), (1, 'washington'), (1, 'virginia'),
       (2, 'harbor'), (2, 'premier'), (2, 'park'),
       (3, 'park'), (3, 'washington'), (3, 'virginia'), (3, 'Ball');
```

I am looking for the id's (parents) that at least have `park, washington and virginia` as name(child).

I have the answer on Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7346/1 but there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called as Conditional Aggregation. I am grouping on Id and then checking whether there is atleast one entry for park,washington,virginia by using having clause and . This should answer your question.

```
SELECT Id
  FROM holdMyBeer
 GROUP BY Id
HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN Name = 'park' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >= 1 AND 
       SUM( CASE WHEN Name = 'washington' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >= 1 AND
       SUM( CASE WHEN Name = 'virginia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >= 1;
```